# Unix Korn Shell - read content of text file into environment variable

Tags: shell, unix, environment-variables, text-files, ksh

I am looking for the most compact way of reading the content of a text file and populating an environment variable, each value to be separated by a comma - ideally avoid writing a loop.

For example, given file.txt

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

The environment variable should look like this:

```
echo $VAR

aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var=$(tr '\n' ',' < file)
```

Comment: @anubhava, But, This will put another comma in last.

Comment: Yes, I know there will be a final comma, I can live with that

Comment: Fixing the final comma, if it mattered, would be as simple as following the above line with `var=${var%,}`...